# Alert before hard disk data corruption occurs that notices both

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

Is there a run time monitor that alerts *before* data corruption occurs that notices both

- media/surface problems
- NTFS logical errors (that chkdsk can fix).

And if there's no active monitor, maybe even an all-in-one program that will check for both?  I know it's a tall order but figure it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: There are hundreds of utilities that will report a problem based on the S.M.A.R.T data you just have to be running them them.  Data corruption does not happen on healthy disks.  Healthy disks do not fail S.M.A.R.T tests or report as being in pre-fail conditions.  There are solutions for just data corruption, its not something you can be "alerted to" you just prevent it by using those solutions.

Comment: What you want is called chkdsk.

Answer (score 0):

There are HDD-specific diagnostic utilities that can help you determine the health and S.M.A.R.T. status of a hard drive. These SMART attributes list the amount of corrupted (bad = remapped) sectors and those that are 'pending'. The pending sector count indicates the amount of unstable sectors (waiting to be remapped). I'd advise you to check your HDD manufacturer's website for such diagnostic tools.